# Why does "not nil" return true in Lua?

Tags: lua, boolean-logic

I have used repl.it to see what it returned, just for the sake of curiosity, and it turned out that 
`not nil`
returnes `true`

Why is it? Is it because in Lua everything should be rather true or false in the end?

Repl.it link: https://repl.it/repls/SanePastelHarrier

Comment: What do you expect the result of expression `not nil` equals to?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `nil` is `false` when converted to boolean:

> **2.2 Booleans**
>
> The boolean type has two values, `false` and `true`, which represent the traditional boolean values. However, booleans do not
>   hold a monopoly of condition values: in Lua, any value may represent a
>   condition. Conditionals (such as the ones in control structures)
>   consider both `false` and `nil` as `false` and anything else as `true`. 
>   Beware that, unlike some other scripting languages, Lua considers both zero
>   and the empty string as `true` in conditional tests.

And `not` treats its argument as a boolean:

> **3.3 Logical Operators**
>
> The logical operators are`and`, `or`, and `not`. Like control structures, all logical operators consider both `false` and `nil`
>   as `false`, and anything else as `true`.